# Is there a way to force window.location.reload() to reload the current URL only one time?

Tags: javascript

I'm testing `window.location.reload()` to see if I can use it to ensure that a client dashboard has the latest value if the client arrives at the dashboard from a forward or back button click.

Unfortunately the default behavior of this method in Chrome and possibly other browsers causes the browser to reload a seemingly endless number of times.

Is there a way to force `window.location.reload()` to reload the current URL only one time?

If I can get that to work maybe I can use `window.history` or some other method to determine if the client arrived at the page from a forward or back button click.  Still researching that.

Comment: Put a flag in local storage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to set a sessionStorage Variable.

```
if(sessionStorage.getItem('loaded') === null) {
  sessionStorage.setItem('loaded', true);
  window.location.reload(); 
}
```